# How to get properties of interface only if variable contains reference to a class that implements that interface?

Tags: typescript, polymorphism

I need to get properties of an object that is of specific interface which contains a reference to a class object. When I print that object I get all the properties of that class.

```
export interface IReporting
{
    Name: string | null;
    KeyValues: Array<KeyValue>;
}
export class AdminReport implements IReporting
{
    Id: number;
    UserIcon: string | null;
    Name: string | null;
    //Key-values
    KeyValues: Array<KeyValue>;
}
In component class:
let updated = <IReporting>(this.report);
console.log(updated);
```

Should expect to see:
Name and KeyValues, but instead get all the properties of AdminReport

Comment: Add some sample code to ilustrate what you are trying to do

Comment: But I send this object to a server and I want it automatically to send all the properties of that object (interface) without me manually choosing each property.

Answer (score 1):

Using a type assertion will not change anything about the underlying runtime object. It just informs the compiler that you expect `report` to be of the shape defined by the interface.

You have to create a new object that contains only the properties you want to send to the server:

```
let updated = <IReporting>{
    KeyValues: report.KeyValues,
    Name: report.Name
}
```

You could create a class that contains only the report properties and copy the information to it from another object. This makes sense if the interface has a lot of properties:

```
export class JustReporting implements IReporting
{
    // All proeprties must be initialized with null or another default so they appear when we call Object.getOwnPropertyNames
    Name: string | null = null;
    KeyValues: Array<KeyValue> = null;
    constructor(data: IReporting) {
        for (const prop of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)) {
            (<any>this)[prop] = (<any>data)[prop];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also added a more automatic way to accomplish this, maybe it is useful to you :)